# Error: operand of '*' must be a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

I seem to be getting this error within my code and when I hover over the bit that says 'data' it says 'Error: operand of '*' must be a pointer'. Can anyone see possibly where the problem lies.

```
double* Matrix::get(int i, int j) const
    {
        return *data[i*N + j];
    }
```

Comment: What is this `data`? And why you're trying to return pointer to `double`, not just a `double`?

Comment: data is the information that is coming from my matrix (array)

Comment: Did you want to return the address of an array element? That's `&` not `*`.

Comment: I will never download a package full of source code to help someone out. Check: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `data` is an array member variable, what you need to say is:

```
return &data[i*N + j];
```

Also, as your function is `const` you should return a const pointer:

```
const double *Matrix::get(int i, int j) const
{
    return &data[i*N + j];
}
```

If you're not looking to have the caller modify the value in the array then change it to:

```
double Matrix::get(int i, int j) const
{
    return data[i*N + j];
}
```

Comment: `data + i*N + j` should be equal `&data[i*N + j]` (of course assuming that `data` is array, raw pointer, or something which behaves like them).

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is an array of double, then get rid of the `*` because you don't need to return the memory address:

```
double Matrix::get(int i, int j) const
{
    return data[i*N + j];
}
```